# Why won't Firefox trace to flashlog.txt in Ubuntu?

Tags: debugging, firefox, ubuntu, actionscript, trace

Okay me and my friend are about to tear our hair out trying to configure the Adobe Flex SDK to work properly on our Ubuntu machine. We have installed and configured the SDK to compile ActionScript files but the FlashPlayer Debugger fails to log traces or errors to flashlog.txt when we execute the compiled swf in Firefox.

We have Flash Player Debugger installed into Firefox and a mm.cfg file located in our home directory.

**Links to what we've tried:**

1. http://www.arulraj.net/2010/08/flash-player-debugger-in-ubuntu.html
2. http://www.gregoryprogrammer.com/2012/12/actionscript-3-code-compilation-in-inux/
3. http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7fc9.html
4. http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/configure-debugger-version-flash-player.html

**Versions of what we're using:**

Firefox Browser 18.0.2

Ubuntu OS 12.0.4

Latest Flex SDK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I notice you didn't mention compiling with the -debug flag.  Here're the steps I take:

- Make sure you're using the debug version of the player (hit [flashplayerversion.com](http://flashplayerversion.com) to check).  This is getting trickier in-browser, especially in 64-bit Linux.  Firefox is probably easier than Chrome these days.  You can also try the debug content projector (aka standalone player) located [here](http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/pub/flashplayer/updaters/11/flashplayer_11_sa_debug.i386.tar.gz).
- Have a ~/mm.cfg file with `TraceOutputFileEnable=1`.  Here's mine:

```
> cat ~/mm.cfg 
ErrorReportingEnable=1
TraceOutputFileEnable=1
```

- Use the trace method somewhere you know it will be executed:

```
> cat Main.as
package {
  import flash.display.Sprite;
  public class Main extends Sprite {
    public function Main() {
      trace("Hello flashlog.txt");
    }
  }
}
```

- Compile the SWF with the -debug option:

```
  mxmlc -debug Main.as
```

- I'll test with the content projector:

```
>flashplayerdebugger Main.swf &
>tail ~/.macromedia/Flash_Player/Logs/flashlog.txt
Hello flashlog.txt
```

Or open a dedicated terminal to follow the log file as it is written:

```
>tail -f ~/.macromedia/Flash_Player/Logs/flashlog.txt
```